# How can other SO questions be moved here

Tags: support

I have answered several Apple questions on other sites especially superuser and I note that when I try to flag then as off-topic I am not given Ask Different as a possible site (of the new sites I can choose webapps or gaming)

How can I ask for these questions to be moved?

Can we get Ask Different added to the list of sites questions can be moved to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Super User is concerned, Apple question are on topic, and unless the questions is about an iPod, iPhone, iPad, or has not received a correct answer in a reasonable amount of time, it will remain on Super User.

Moderators, as Dori mentioned, has the ability to move to any site, however each question is reviewed carefully before it's moved.

Comment: So the same question can be on topic here and on SuperUser?

Comment: @Mark. Correct. OSX and Apple Hardware questions are within scope for Super User and always will be, which is why Ask Different is not a migration path. If your question is about an Apple Device then it is off topic for Super User.

Comment: @Diago Then, what's exactly the rule: when the question is better posted at Superuser then here at AskDifferent?